# jQuery Chained selects and coldfusion JSON issues

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a page which is using jquery.chained.select to link together 2 select boxes, one is a select box for brands and the other is a multiple select box which is populated with the products which fall under the brand which is selected.

Im using Adobe Coldfusion. The problem is that there are over 15000 products in the database so a normal cfquery which returns the results for the product select box makes the page very very slow when it loads. I have created another page which returns the product results in JSON, however i cannot get the multiple select box to load with the products in the multiple select. Below is the script i am using to get the JSON from the prod-json.cfm page and populate the select box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// JavaScript Document
// The queryToObject function
var queryToObject = function(q) {
var col, i, r, _i, _len, _ref, _ref2, _results;
_results = [];
for (i = 0, _ref = q.ROWCOUNT; 0 <= _ref ? i < _ref : i > _ref; 0 <= _ref ? i++ : i--) {
  r = {};
  _ref2 = q.COLUMNS;
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref2.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    col = _ref2[_i];
    r[col.toLowerCase()] = q.DATA[col][i];
  }
  _results.push(r);
}
return _results;
};

// Read the products
$.ajax({

data: {brand_id: val},
url: "prod-json.cfm",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
  var row, sData, _len, _i;
  // Run the data thru queryToObject
  data = queryToObject(data);
  // Convert the object to a string to display it
  sData = JSON.stringify(data);

  // Print all products
  $('#product_id').append('');
  // Loop over the query
  for (_i = 0, _len = data.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    row = data[_i];
    $('.multiple').append('<option value=' + row.product_id + ' class="' + row.brand_id + '">' +     row.product_title + ' - ' + row.make_title + ' ' + row.model_title + '');
  }
}
});
</script>
```

This is the jquery chained script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {

/* For jquery.chained.js */
$("#product_id").chained("#brand_id");

});
</script>
```

These are the select boxes:

```
<p><label>Brand:<br />
<select name="brand_id" id="brand_id" class="styled">
<option value="0">None...</option>
<cfloop query="getbrand">
<option value="#brand_id#">#brand_name#</option>
</cfloop>
</select></label>
</p>


<p><label>Products:<br />
<select name="product_id" id="product_id" multiple="multiple" class="multiple">
</select>
</label>
</p>
```

The top script should append results to the product_id select box in the correct format so that the chained script will work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does prod-json.cfm do? in particular, what data does it return?

Comment: It returns a list of the product title with make and model id and also brand id

Comment: Ok, so does the request get fired and does the response look ok? If you set a breakpoint in your browser's debug tools, how far does the success callback get?

Comment: From what i just saw now, it says this: ReferenceError: val is not defined, i assume that is the brand_id val in the data section of the main script at the top. The value that is selected from the brand_id select box has to get passed to this URL with a variable at the end: prod-json.cfm?brand_id=115

Comment: so you need a JS event listener on your select boxes that updates the `val` and makes the ajax call... that should really be in a function on its own which you can then call when you need to.

Comment: Ok, how would i implement that to the current code?